# Botões em uma Gtk.CellRenderer

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, gtk-python

Estou tentando fazer um programa que salva algumas informações em um BD, consigo apresentar as informações na janela sem problema algum, porém eu queria adicionar 2 botões por linha um "Editar" e outro "Apagar", porém não existe um método "CellRedererButton" apenas "spin, spinner, toggle, radio", gostaria de saber como posso fazer para adicionar esse botão já que não existe um método próprio para isso

Login.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Python 3 GTK+ 3

Arquivo LoginWin.py
"""
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from Index import Index


class LoginWin(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Título da janela.
        self.set_title('Tela de login')
        # Definindo o ícone da janela (caminho relativo ou absoluto).
        # self.set_default_icon_from_file('../../_static/favicon.png')
        # Tamanho da janela.
        self.set_default_size(1366 / 2, 768 / 2)
        # Posição em que a janela será iniciada.
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        # Definindo uma borda entre a janela principal e o container (Grid layout).
        self.set_border_width(10)

        # Grid
        grid = Gtk.Grid.new()
        grid.set_row_spacing(10)
        self.add(grid)

        self.login_txt = Gtk.Entry.new()
        self.login_txt.set_placeholder_text('Login')

        self.senha_txt = Gtk.Entry.new()
        self.senha_txt.set_placeholder_text('Senha')

        self.login_btn = Gtk.Button.new_with_label('Login')
        self.login_btn.connect('clicked', self.login)
        self.set_focus(self.login_btn)

        grid.add(self.login_txt)
        grid.attach_next_to(self.senha_txt, self.login_txt, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 2)
        grid.attach_next_to(self.login_btn, self.senha_txt, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 2)



        # sqlite

    def login(self, widget):
        # Escondendo a janela.
        # self.set_visible(False)
        self.hide()

        # Exibindo a outra janela e passando pra ela LoginWin(Gtk.Window).
        # Isso porque vamos precisar exibir essa janela de novo.
        Index(parent=self).show_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = LoginWin()
    win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Index.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Python 3 GTK+ 3.

Arquivo Index.py.

    """
    import gi

    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import Gtk

    result_list = [(1, "Pegasus", "g****@.com", "password", "Conta", False, False),
                   (2, "gseganzrla", "g.*@.com", "senha", "Conta", False, False)]


    class Index(Gtk.Window):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            """Construtor.

            :param parent: Está recebendo LoginWin(Gtk.Window).
            """
            super().__init__()
            self.set_title('Table')
            # self.set_default_icon_from_file('../../_static/favicon.png')
            self.set_default_size(1366 / 2, 768 / 2)
            self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
            self.set_border_width(10)

            # Atribuindo parent (LoginWin(Gtk.Window) em uma variável.
            self.parent = parent

            # Widges.
            self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
            self.grid.set_column_homogeneous(True)
            self.grid.set_row_homogeneous(True)
            self.add(self.grid)

            self.box = Gtk.Box()
            self.list_button = Gtk.Button()

            # Criando listsore
            self.result_liststore = Gtk.ListStore(int, str, str, str, str, bool, bool)
            for result_ref in result_list:
                self.result_liststore.append(list(result_ref))
                print("Resultado {}".format(result_ref))

            self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.result_liststore)
            self.buton = Gtk.Button()
            for i, column_title in enumerate(["ID", "Usuario", "Email", "Senha", "Conta", "Editar", "Apagar"]):
                renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
                self.treeview.append_column(column)

            # sesson_destroy()
            self.session_destroy = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Seasson Destroy")
            self.session_destroy.connect("clicked", self.encerrar_sessao)

            self.fechar = Gtk.Button(label="Fechar")
            self.fechar.connect("clicked", Gtk.main_quit)

            self.scrollable_treelist = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
            self.scrollable_treelist.set_vexpand(True)
            self.grid.attach(self.scrollable_treelist, 0, 0, 8, 10)
            self.grid.attach_next_to(self.session_destroy, self.scrollable_treelist, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 1)
            self.grid.attach_next_to(self.fechar, self.session_destroy, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)

            self.scrollable_treelist.add(self.treeview)

            self.show_all()


        def encerrar_sessao(self, widget):
            print('Encerrando a sessão')

            # Escondendo a janela.
            # self.set_visible(False)
            # self.hide()

            # Destruindo a janela.
            self.destroy()

            # Exibindo a tela de login (LoginWin(Gtk.Window)).
            # self.parent.set_visible(True)
            self.parent.show_all()

        def close(self, widget):
            print('Fechando aplicativo')

            # Encerrando o aplicativo.
            Gtk.main_quit()
```

Comment: Realmente não existe um widget `CellRedererButton`, neste caso você teria que criar uma classe e nessa classe herdar de Gtk.CellRender e fazer um overriding nos métodos ou métodos virtuais dessa classe.

As únicas referencias que encontrei sobre isso foi no Stack Overflow em inglês:

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464459/creating-a-custom-gtkcellrenderer-with-pygobject).

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596268/how-to-write-a-custom-gtk-cellrenderer-which-would-show-gtk-colorbutton).

Comment: Uma sugestão que pode facilitar seu trabalho ao criar telas é criar a tela no Glade e importar o arquivo xml pelo Gtk. É bem mais rápido e fácil!